# Split beamer frame into two horizontal subframes, each with a different set of environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, columns

I am trying to divide my slide into two horizontal parts, the top part containing a mathematical expression on the top left side, and the bottom part containing two columns, listing the applications of the expression. However, when I try the following code, I get some overlap. How can I fix this? I tried many different environments for the tikzpicture; block, minipage, etc, but all give the same problem. Code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 


%% start
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Applications} 
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
        optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            fill=gray!10,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
        }, 
        information text/.style={%
            rounded corners, 
            fill=blue!10, 
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
        }
        ]

        \draw node[below right=1 cm and 0.5cm of current page.north west, opacity=0.3, style=optimization problem] (prob)
        {
        $
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \textup{minimize} & \mu \\
        \textup{subject to} & f(\mu)\leq 1.          
        \end{array}
        $
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}


    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first
                \item second 
                \item third
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \hfill
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first
                \item second 
                \item third
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}        
    \end{columns}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear, what result of your code you expect and why you need absolute positioning of images on the slide. After rearranges your document preamble, removing absolute positioning of each image in presentation and the first `minipage` on slide, I obtain the following result:

[image]

which is produced by:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}


%% start
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Applications}
\tikzset{base/.style = {}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
optimization problem/.style = {rounded corners, fill=gray!10, opacity=0.3,
                               inner ysep=2pt, inner xsep=1pt,
                               align=center},
                ]
        \node[optimization problem] (prob)
            {$\begin{array}{ll}
              \text{minimize}   & \mu \\
              \text{subject to} & f(\mu)\leq 1.
            \end{array}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first
                \item second
                \item third
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \hfill
        \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item first
                \item second
                \item third
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, nothing on slide overlap with any its elements.

To my opinion it is more sensible, that you would remove the second `minipage` too and by this make more (horizontal) space for both lists:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! This is very helpful. Just to understand your solution a bit better, what did removing the line about remember picture and overlay help? I am still a beginner and a lot of my code is just written by finding fixes on tex stackexchnage to similar bugs and copying them, and that line was from one such answer, so I don't really know what it does. 

Also, is absolute positioning not a good way to go about? I want the math to be at the top, and I want the two columns beneath it -- what alternative approach would you suggest?

Thanks a lot, once again!

Comment: @lazulikid, for the slide, which you show code, I don't see any reasons that image should be absolute positioning. This only can make problems since image is fixed on slide and consequently it may overlap with slide headers (if you use some presentation theme). BTW, if you need only simple box, without transparency (in this particular case I would not use it), you could use `beamercolorbox` (see12.5 Framed and Boxed Text, page 125, Beamer manual). You may find http://faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/beamer_guide.pdf` interesting.

Comment: Thanks so much once again. One last question (sorry to bug you so much!) -- I have the need to write math in boxes throughout my presentation. If not absolute positioning using nodes, what would you recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: See http://recherche.noiraudes.net/en/LaTeX.php, it may help you. also see manual for `beamer`, there are descriptions of boxes prepared for your need: `beamercolorbox`, `beamerboxrounded`, boxes for theorems  etc.